# How to override devise routes from plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am building plugin for my engine which will enable user to login via socials networks like facebook and twitter.

I came to a part where i need to override devise user routes from plugin, which i have configured in engine.

If i set in dummy application:

`devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }`

I have working omniauth, but i need to load this controller from plugin.

How i am supposed to do this?

My callbacks controller:

```
class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
    @user = MyEngine::User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    sign_in_and_redirect @user
  end

  def twitter
    @user = MyEngine::User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    sign_in_and_redirect @user
  end
end
```

Comment: I didn't understand what is your problem. To load this `Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController` you only need the omniauth in your GemFile

Comment: Yes but i need callbacks controller actions, i have `The action 'facebook' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController`

Comment: please show `rake routes | grep facebook`